# The issue is with the fix navigation menu in Bootstrap 4. Something I am missing which makes this issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I had a problem with my fixed navigation using bootstrap 4. 
It is okay for the nav item on hover which has not the class active. But the problem is when I hover over the active nav item it shows two border bottoms.
I need help here. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <!-- bootstrap.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">

<div class="container-fluid ">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top mainNavigation navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Next World</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#homeNav" aria-controls="homeNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="homeNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#team">Our Team</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#product">Our Product</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Our Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    </nav>  
</div>  


<!-- other -->
<div id="home" style="height: 500px;">Home</div>
<div id="about" style="height: 500px;">About</div>
<div id="team" style="height: 500px;">Team</div>
<div id="product" style="height: 500px;">Product</div>
<div id="services" style="height: 500px;">Services</div>
<div id="contact" style="height: 500px;">contact</div>
    <!-- jquery link -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- popper.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap.min.js -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css is as given below

```
.mainNavigation{
    background-color: #fff !important;
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.nav-link{
    color: rgb(165, 29, 43) !important;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item{
    padding-top: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-item{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(165, 29, 43);
        padding-top: 0px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item .active {
        opacity: 1;
        border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(165, 29, 43);
        padding-top: 0px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/de_pes08/k12vgu3q/

Comment: if you comment off `border-bottom: solid 2px rgb(165, 29, 43); ` from `.navbar-nav .nav-item .active`, then only one bottom-border will be displayed.

Comment: If you remove the space between the .nav-item and .active so that it reads .navbar-nav .nav-item.active is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple CSS logic to solve this porblem.
Just make a logic like:
if we hover the list (li) expressed by .nav-item, then the .nav-link.active (both .nav-link & .active) will show no extra bottom border.

the exact css code will be like:

```
  .nav-item:hover a.nav-link.active {
    border: none;
}
```

Note: if you test the css in live, then you will see the .active list element shows with a little delay like others. If you don't need that, just remove transition-delay from your source css file.

Thanks.